# Base de datos con socket.io y node.js

Tags: mysql, nodejs, socket.io

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación del tipo messenger. Me conecto a la base de datos mediante node.js mysql. Cada persona que se loguea en la página web se conecta inicialmente a un room por ejemplo: "room juan" (solo juan se conecta a esta sala) dicho room lo utilizo para actualizar la lista de amigos de este usuario

```
socket.join("room juan"); //cada usuario tiene su propio room y nadie más ingresa //en el
socket.join("juan");
```

cuando un usuario se loguea aparece con el status "conectado" en la base de datos. (Los registros que tienen repetido el "room juan" es porque son amigos de juan)

```
 users_online

    room      |    nickname     | status
    -------------------------------------------
    room juan |     juan        | **desconectado**
    -------------------------------------------
    room juan |     maria       | desconectado
    -------------------------------------------
    room ana  |     dario       | desconectado
```

Juan se logueo, entonces seteo su status a conectado

```
setStatusToConnected(juan); 


function setStatusToConnected("juan")
 {

           con.query(      
           'UPDATE users_online SET status = "connected" WHERE nickname = ?', ["juan"]);
  }
```

La base de datos actualiza y el status de Juan esta como conectado ahora

```
    users_online

    room      |    nickname     | status
    -------------------------------------------
    room juan |     juan        | **conectado**
    -------------------------------------------
    room juan |     maria       | desconectado
    -------------------------------------------
    room ana  |     dario       | desconectado
```

actualizo los usuarios online, en este array `friend_list = [];` almaceno los usuarios con status conectados

```
updateUsersOnline(room juan, juan);


function updateUsersOnline(room juan,juan) {

friend_list = [];

           con.query(      
   'SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE status="connected"',
   [room],

  function(err,rows){
    if(err) throw err;

    for (var i in rows) {

             var obj = { room: rows[i].room, nickname: rows[i].nickname}; 

               friend_list.push(obj);

                io.sockets.in(rows[i].room).emit('view_data',      friend_list,rows[i].room); 

    }
            }
    );
```

emito un evento por cada room que posee al usuario recientemente conectado, es decir que si varios usuarios estan conectados al room de juan emito un evento para dichos rooms que posean al usuario en cuestión y actualizo el listado que muestra los users online

```
        io.sockets.in(rows[i].room).emit('view_data',      friend_list,rows[i].room); 


CLIENTE



 socket.on('view_data', function (friends,room){


                        for(var i=0; i<friends.length; i++) {
                                    if(friends[i].room==room){

     console.log(friendList[i].nickname);
    }

     }
```

Mi pregunta es, esta forma de mostrar los amigos del user que se loguea en la pagina, es una buena práctica?, esta bien?, a la larga puede conllevar problemas?, es la única forma que se me ocurrió para actualizar y poder guardar los contactos de los usuarios. Luego quisiera almacenar los mensajes de los usuarios cuando se comunican entre sí, por ejemplo la tabla sería de este estilo:

```
 tabla_mensajes

        origen    |  destinatario   | mensaje
        -------------------------------------------
        maria     |     juan        | hola juan como estas?
        -------------------------------------------
        juan      |     maria       | muy bien y vos?
        -------------------------------------------
        maria     |     juan        | tambien :)
```

y cuando el usuario clickea sobre el amigo que desea conversar en el cliente creo un evento que se comunique con el servidor solicitando los mensajes antiguos como por ejemplo:

```
'SELECT mensaje FROM tabla_mensajes WHERE origen=? AND destinatario=?'
```

(O algo por el estilo) , ¿que les parece?, ¿estoy yendo por el camino correcto o no?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN: El esquema anterior no iba del todo bien, este sí**

Se me ocurre esto:

Tendrías:

- a. Tu tabla **usuarios**
- b. Una tabla **conversaciones** que servirá para agrupar cualquier conversación. A esta tabla se le puede agregar por ejemplo una columna fecha o cualquier otra información que pueda serte útil.
- c. Una tabla **usuarios_conversaciones** que servirá de puente entre las tablas a y b. En esta tabla pondrás en relación todos los mensajes intercambiados entre dos o más usuarios en una conversación determinada. La misma podría llevar una columna del tipo datetime si te interesa saber la fecha y hora exacta de cualquier mensaje.

No es necesario que en la tabla mensajes (a la que yo he llamado conversaciones) almacenes **de nuevo** el nombre del usuario, ya lo tienes en tu tabla de usuarios y ahora sólo haces referencia al mismo por medio de su id. De esta manera las tablas permanecen optimizadas y son más rápidas a la hora de obtener información. **No es lo mismo una tabla mensajes con miles de líneas en las que repites una y otra vez juan->maría, maría->juan, en vez de 1->2,2->1... ** en un chat con miles de usuarios tu tabla mensajes crecería de una forma increíble y se haría muy pesada si usas información redundante.

***Nota:*** Los esquemas son básicos, para tener una idea. Habría que mejorarlos creando los índices respectivos en cada tabla.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/922e8d/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios
    (`id_usuario` int, `nombre_usuario` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO usuarios
    (`id_usuario`, `nombre_usuario`)
VALUES
    (1, 'juan'),
    (2, 'maria'),
    (3, 'pedro')
;

CREATE TABLE conversaciones
    (`id_conversacion` int)
;

INSERT INTO conversaciones
    (`id_conversacion`)
VALUES
    (1);

CREATE TABLE usuarios_conversaciones
    (`id` int, `id_usuario_origen` int, `id_usuario_destino` int, `id_conversacion` int, `mensaje` varchar(250))
;

INSERT INTO usuarios_conversaciones
    (`id`, `id_conversacion`, `id_usuario_origen`, `id_usuario_destino`, `mensaje`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1, 2, 'hola maría'),
    (2,1,2, 1, 'hola juan'),
    (3,1,1, 2, '¿como estás?'),
    (4,1,2, 1, 'todo bien :)')


;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  uo.nombre_usuario u_origen, ud.nombre_usuario, uc.mensaje
FROM
  usuarios uo
LEFT JOIN usuarios_conversaciones uc
  ON uo.id_usuario = uc.id_usuario_origen 
LEFT JOIN usuarios ud
  ON ud.id_usuario = uc.id_usuario_destino 
  WHERE uc.id_conversacion=1 
 ORDER BY uc.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/922e8d/1/0)**:

> ```
> | nombre_usuario | nombre_usuario |      mensaje |
> |----------------|----------------|--------------|
> |           juan |          maria |   hola maría |
> |          maria |           juan |    hola juan |
> |           juan |          maria | ¿como estás? |
> |          maria |           juan | todo bien :) |
> ```