# Diferenciar roles de usuario en consulta

Tags: php

saludos amigos tengo un problema con una consulta en sesiones, tengo un mini foro interno entre usuarios y administrador el me registra bien y se muestran los mjs bien el único problema que tengo es a la hora de mostrar los nombres osea me explico:

mensaje admin

> `Administrador: Admin  Dice al Usuario: oswaldo moriche (aqui deberia decir el nombre y apellido del usuario y dice es el nombre y
>   apellido del administrador)`

mensaje usuario

> `Usuario: Admin(aqui deberia ir el nombre del usuario)  Dice al Administrador: Admin`

anexo las consulta y su imagen para ver si me entiendo mejor

```
 consulta para los mjs del administrador

 <?php
 $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login']);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['password']);
 $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM foro, usuario WHERE 
 usuario.login='$login' AND 
 usuario.password='$password' AND 
 foro.foros='respuesta' AND
 foro.fk_cedula_admin=usuario.id";
 $resultl=mysql_query($sql3,$link) or die("Error en: $sql: " . 
 mysql_error());
 while ($lista=mysql_fetch_array($resultl)){
 ?>

 consulta para los mensajes de los usuarios

 <?php
 $login= $_SESSION['login'];
 $password=$_SESSION['password'];
 $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM foro, usuario WHERE usuario.login='$login' AND 
 usuario.password='$password' AND foro.foros='pregunta' AND
 foro.fk_cedula_admin=usuario.id";
 $resultl=mysql_query($sql4,$link) or die("Error en: $sql: " . 
 mysql_error());
 while ($lista=mysql_fetch_array($resultl)){
 ?>
```

tabla foro:

```
 id, descripcion, fecha, fk_cedula_admin, fk_cedula_user,foros
```

tabla usuario:

```
 id, cedula, nombre, apellido, login, password, idnivel_usuario
```

Imágenes de apoyo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50248/29967)  se aproxima a lo que necesitas. En ella se requería manejar los mensajes de un chat entre dos o más personas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar tantos [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) como necesites (incluso a la misma tabla, en este caso a la tabla `usuario`) para conseguir traducir los identificadores de cada usuario en cada mensaje:

```
SELECT
  id_foro, descripcion, fecha, foros,
  ur.nombre ur_nombre,
  ur.apellido ur_apellido,
  ur.idnivel_usuario ur_idnivel_usuario,
  ud.nombre ud_nombre,
  ud.apellido ud_apellido,
  ud.idnivel_usuario ud_idnivel_usuario
FROM
  foro f
INNER JOIN
  usuario ur
ON
  f.fk_cedula_admin = ur.id
INNER JOIN
  usuario ud
ON
  f.fk_cedula_user = ud.id
WHERE
  f.foros IN ('pregunta', 'respuesta')
  AND
    (
      f.fk_cedula_admin = '$id_usuario'
    OR
      f.fk_cedula_user = '$id_usuario'
    )
```

Donde las tablas `ur` son los usuarios remitentes y la `ud` los usuarios destinatarios.

He editado la consulta para obtener los datos de las tablas y asignarles un `alias` con el que puedas acceder a ellos fácilmente desde PHP.

Como no tengo muy claro quién es destinatario o destinatario según el esquema de tu tabla, asumo que debería coincidir el `id` de usuario con `fk_cedula_admin` o `fk_cedula_user` de la tabla del foro.

La idea es que entiendas cómo obtener los datos mediante uniones (`JOIN`) de tablas.

---

**Edito: repito código de la respuesta anterior**

Insisto en que en las variables de sesión no deberías guardar el usuario y contraseña, si no algo que identifique al usuario de la sesión de manera unívoca.

Te propuse usar su clave primaria o `id` y te puse el siguiente código para obtenerlo a partir de las variables de sesión que ya tenías definidas:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario.id'])) {
  $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login']);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['password']);
  $sql = "SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' AND 
password='$password'";
  $resultl = mysql_query($sql,$link);//devuelve la consulta
  if ($resultl === false) {
    die(mysql_error());
  }
  $_editar_linea = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultl);
  if ($_editar_linea === false) {
    die('Acceso denegado');
  }
  $_SESSION['usuario.id'] = $_editar_linea['id'];
}
$id_usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['usuario.id']);
```

Ten en cuenta que es posible hacer la consulta sin esta variable, pero agregaría un nivel adicional de unión entre tablas innecesario.

---

**Edición con el contenido final**

Tras compartir en el chat el código completo y el esquema de la base de datos, el resultado completo ha sido:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario.id'])) {
  $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login']);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['password']);
  $sql = "SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' AND 
password='$password'";
  $resultl = mysql_query($sql,$link);//devuelve la consulta
  if ($resultl === false) {
    die(mysql_error());
  }
  $_editar_linea = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultl);
  if ($_editar_linea === false) {
    die('Acceso denegado');
  }
  $_SESSION['usuario.id'] = $_editar_linea['id'];
}
$id_usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['usuario.id']);
$sql = "
SELECT
  id_foro, descripcion, fecha, foros,
  IF(foros = 'respuesta', ur.nombre, ud.nombre) ur_nombre,
  IF(foros = 'respuesta', ur.apellido, ud.apellido) ur_apellido,
  IF(foros = 'respuesta', ur.idnivel_usuario, ud.idnivel_usuario) ur_idnivel_usuario,
  IF(foros = 'respuesta', ud.nombre, ur.nombre) ud_nombre,
  IF(foros = 'respuesta', ud.apellido, ur.apellido) ud_apellido,
  IF(foros = 'respuesta', ud.idnivel_usuario, ur.idnivel_usuario) ud_idnivel_usuario
FROM
  foro f
INNER JOIN
  usuario ur
ON
  f.fk_cedula_admin = ur.id
INNER JOIN
  usuario ud
ON
  f.fk_cedula_user = ud.id
WHERE
  f.foros IN ('pregunta', 'respuesta')
  AND
    (
      f.fk_cedula_admin = '$id_usuario'
    OR
      f.fk_cedula_user = '$id_usuario'
    )
";
$resultl = mysql_query($sql,$link) or die("Error en: $sql: " . 
mysql_error());
//$campo = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultl);


while ($lista=mysql_fetch_array($resultl)){
?>


<br>

<!-- MENSAJE-->
<div class="col s12 m12">
<div class="card-panel green lighten-4 z-depth-1">
<div class="right-align">
<form action='eliminarforo.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='codforo' value="<?= htmlspecialchars($lista['id_foro']) ?>">
<input type='image' src='../imagenes/cerrar.png' width='25' height='25' title='borrar'>
</form>
</div>
<div class="row valign-wrapper">
<div class="col s2">
<img src="../avatar/avatar.png" class="circle responsive-img" width="100px" height="100px">
</div>
<div class="col s4 card-panel blue lighten-2">
<h5 class="black-text text-darken-2 left CONDENSED LIGHT5"><?= htmlspecialchars($lista['ur_idnivel_usuario']) ?>:
  <?= htmlspecialchars($lista['ur_nombre']) ?> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($lista['ur_apellido']) ?></h5>   
</div>

<div class="col s6 card-panel grey darken-2">
<h5 class="white-text text-darken-2 left CONDENSED LIGHT5">
Dice al <?= htmlspecialchars($lista['ud_idnivel_usuario']) ?>:
  <?= htmlspecialchars($lista['ud_nombre']) ?> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($lista['ud_apellido']) ?>
</h5>   
</div>
</div>


<div class="card-panel green lighten-4 z-depth-2">
<div style="width:100%; word-wrap: break-word;">
<h6 class="black-text left-align">Comentario: <?php echo $lista['descripcion']; ?></h6>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col s2 card-panel blue-grey darken-4 right">
<h6 class="white-text text-darken-2 center-align CONDENSED LIGHT5">
<?php echo $lista['fecha']; ?>
</h6>   
</div>
<br>

        </div>
      </div>
<!-- FIN MENSAJE-->
<?php
}
```

Las modificaciones incluyen:

- SQL propuesto en esta respuesta.
- Cambio de `<?php echo ... ?>` a `<?= htmlspecialchars( ... ) ?>`.
- Convertir dos bucles (mensajes enviados y mensajes recibidos) a uno único en el que el remitente y destinatario se obtiene del registro y no de las variables de sesión.
- Intercambio de remitentes y destinatarios en caso de que sea del tipo `pregunta` o `respuesta` (lo fácil hecho difícil).

Comment: ok te entiendo lo he puesto en marcha, pero me da error `Notice: Undefined variable: usuario_id in C: on line 147
Notice: Undefined variable: usuario_id in C: on line 149
Notice: Undefined variable: usuario_id in C: on line 151
Notice: Undefined variable: usuario_id in C: on line 151
Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C: on line 152
`

Comment: `Error en: : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR f.fk_cedula_user = OR f.fk_cedula_admin = OR ' at line 17 `

Comment: ¿Recuerdas el código que te puse en la pregunta anterior? Úsalo para definir la variable `$usuario_id`. En cuanto pueda edito la respuesta con el código completo.

Comment: Edición realizada. La he hecho desde el móvil, no sé si me habré colado algo por el camino. Si explicas un poco mejor el significado de los campos en tu pregunta (qué campo es el destinatario, el remitente, etc) podré hacerte la consulta SQL mejor (ésta es una tentativa inicial).

Comment: el campo del administrador es fk_cedula_admin y el del usuario es fk_cedula_user

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y recuerda que lo que me has explicado tiene sentido en tu cabeza, donde tienes todo pensado, pero nos tienes que explicar (con algún ejemplo mejor) lo que significan esas palabras.

Comment: listo mira la imagen creo que la imagen lo dice todo

Comment: Para tí la imagen lo explica, pero para mí el esquema de tu tabla es un galimatías. Una tabla de mensajes debería tener únicamente clave primaria, foro (si hay varios), fecha, usuario remitente, destinatario y contenido del mensaje. El resto de campos se obtienen de las relaciones con otras tablas (listado de usuarios, foros, etc).

Comment: ¿En qué estado se encuentra tu aplicación? ¿Está en fase de desarrollo/diseño o de producción/explotación? Pasemos al chat y seguimos hablando por ahí.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58101/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-yoclens).